# Show that $T$ is a subring of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a multiplicative (commutative) ring with multiplicative identity. For $b \in R$ let $$T = bR = Rb = \{rb : r \in R\}$$ be the subset of $R$ consisting of multiples of $b$. Show that $T$ is a subring of $R$.

All I basically have to do is just say for any $c  \in R$ we have $(b - c)r \in R$ and we have $brcr = (bcr)r \in R$ and I am done. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $T$ is a subring, you have to show that $br - br'$, $br \cdot br'$ and $0$ are in $T$ for any $r,r'\in R$. All these verifications should be easy.